# Apple Mach-O Linker Error - after install cocoapods

Tags: ios, xcode, google-analytics, cocoapods

This error happens, when in my existing xcodeproject, i installing cocoapods. ( want to use canvas for animation).
after i successful create that pods, i got an error on google analytics (not in pods)

my podfile :
platform :ios, '7.0'
pod 'Canvas'

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64: "_NSOverwriteMergePolicy", referenced from: +[TAGModel contextWithURL:] in libGoogleAnalyticsServices.a(TAGModel.o) -[GAIDataStore contextWithModel:URL:] in libGoogleAnalyticsServices.a(GAIDataStore.o) "_NSSQLiteErrorDomain", referenced from: -[GAIDataStore performBlockAndWait:withError:] in libGoogleAnalyticsServices.a(GAIDataStore.o) "_NSSQLiteStoreType", referenced from: +[TAGModel coordinatorWithURL:] in libGoogleAnalyticsServices.a(TAGModel.o) -[GAIDataStore coordinatorWithModel:URL:] in libGoogleAnalyticsServices.a(GAIDataStore.o) "_OBJC_CLASS_$_NSAttributeDescription", referenced from: objc-class-ref in libGoogleAnalyticsServices.a(TAGModel.o) objc-class-ref in libGoogleAnalyticsServices.a(GAICoreDataUtil.o) "_OBJC_CLASS_$_NSEntityDescription", referenced from: objc-class-ref in libGoogleAnalyticsServices.a(TAGDataProvider.o) objc-class-ref in libGoogleAnalyticsServices.a(TAGModel.o) objc-class-ref in libGoogleAnalyticsServices.a(GAIDataStore.o) objc-class-ref in libGoogleAnalyticsServices.a(GAICoreDataUtil.o) "_OBJC_CLASS_$_NSFetchRequest", referenced from: objc-class-ref in libGoogleAnalyticsServices.a(TAGModel.o) objc-class-ref in libGoogleAnalyticsServices.a(GAIDataStore.o) "_OBJC_CLASS_$_NSManagedObject", referenced from: _OBJC_CLASS_$_TAGHit in libGoogleAnalyticsServices.a(TAGHit.o) _OBJC_CLASS_$_GAIHit in libGoogleAnalyticsServices.a(GAIHit.o) _OBJC_CLASS_$_GAIProperty in libGoogleAnalyticsServices.a(GAIProperty.o) "_OBJC_CLASS_$_NSManagedObjectContext", referenced from: objc-class-ref in libGoogleAnalyticsServices.a(TAGModel.o) objc-class-ref in libGoogleAnalyticsServices.a(GAIDataStore.o) "_OBJC_CLASS_$_NSManagedObjectModel", referenced from: objc-class-ref in libGoogleAnalyticsServices.a(TAGModel.o) objc-class-ref in libGoogleAnalyticsServices.a(GAICoreDataUtil.o) "_OBJC_CLASS_$_NSPersistentStoreCoordinator", referenced from: objc-class-ref in libGoogleAnalyticsServices.a(TAGModel.o) objc-class-ref in libGoogleAnalyticsServices.a(GAIDataStore.o) "_OBJC_METACLASS_$_NSManagedObject", referenced from: _OBJC_METACLASS_$_TAGHit in libGoogleAnalyticsServices.a(TAGHit.o) _OBJC_METACLASS_$_GAIHit in libGoogleAnalyticsServices.a(GAIHit.o) _OBJC_METACLASS_$_GAIProperty in libGoogleAnalyticsServices.a(GAIProperty.o) "_deflate", referenced from: +[GAICompressionUtil gai_dataByCompressingBytes:length:compressionLevel:mode:] in libGoogleAnalyticsServices.a(GAICompressionUtil.o) "_deflateEnd", referenced from: +[GAICompressionUtil gai_dataByCompressingBytes:length:compressionLevel:mode:] in libGoogleAnalyticsServices.a(GAICompressionUtil.o) "_deflateInit2_", referenced from: +[GAICompressionUtil gai_dataByCompressingBytes:length:compressionLevel:mode:] in libGoogleAnalyticsServices.a(GAICompressionUtil.o) "_inflate", referenced from: +[GAICompressionUtil gai_dataByInflatingBytes:length:isRawData:] in libGoogleAnalyticsServices.a(GAICompressionUtil.o) "_inflateEnd", referenced from: +[GAICompressionUtil gai_dataByInflatingBytes:length:isRawData:] in libGoogleAnalyticsServices.a(GAICompressionUtil.o) "_inflateInit2_", referenced from: +[GAICompressionUtil gai_dataByInflatingBytes:length:isRawData:] in libGoogleAnalyticsServices.a(GAICompressionUtil.o) ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64 clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

what should i do to fix that things? 
thank you =D

Comment: Have you used xcworkspace rather than xcproject?

Answer (score 0):

I already fixed that error.

if someone got an error like me, please double check again the codebase google analytics files. and please add again.

Thanks.